# How to draw shapes on Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How do I draw the shape on Google MAP using Google MAP Javascript API as per attached image?

Please let me know , if you need more information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6IWy.png)

Comment: What do you mean by as per attached image? Do you mean layer?

Comment: Yeah, Layer. How do I create a layer as the attached image ?

Comment: Do you want more information ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, is this really what you are looking for, anyway, how about this one?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

You can also [use the data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data) and set the drawing mode to true, which gives you a lot more options.